# fs.appendFile: is any of variants to use FUNCTION instead of STRING params?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

As we see in the [nodejs API](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_filename_data_options_callback), `fs.appendFile(filename, data, [options], callback)` doesn't document that a function to be passed as an argument for `data`.

For `data` can I pass a function instead of string?

For example:

**module items.js contains:**

```
var items = {};
exports.items=items;
```

**the file.js contains:**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var items = require('./items.js');

function consolLog(){
  fs.readFile('./items.js',function(err,data){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
  })
}

function writeToFile (itemNummer, price){
  items[itemNummer] = [];
  return items[itemNummer].push(price);
}
```

**// here is the core of question: is any way to use a Function (var, etc) instead of String**

```
fs.appendFile('./items.js', writeToFile(12345, 123),function(err){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(consolLog());
})
```

Comment: do you ask about to put a function reference or a function call?

Comment: Did you try it?  If so, did you get an error?

Comment: there is no error, but writeToFile(param,param) become a String, and append a String to a file!

Comment: i need to append a new data to the OBJECT everytime user Submit new Value from FORM tag! I need to update this file with OBJECT inside, but Node's fs.Module only submit String value! So i am searching a way, maybe some module, that change param of fs.appendFile(**data**) to Function! If it is not exist, what way i have to look, to cope with my task?